# error attempting to merge PDFs with bookmark using sejda-console

Tags: sejda

I have downloaded sejda-console and want to use it to merge PDFs and create a table of contents bookmarking each of the merged PDF in the output document.  I thought I understood the syntax, but I am encountering an error:

```
$ ~/sejda-console-1.0.0.M10/bin/sejda-console merge -e "Analog_2015-03-(.*)k2opt.pdf" -b one_entry_each_doc -o Analog_2015-03_sejda.pdf
12:35:55.410 Configuring Sejda 1.0.0.M10
12:35:55.430 Loading Sejda configuration form default sejda.xml
12:35:55.549 Starting execution with arguments: 'merge -e Analog_2015-03-(.*)k2opt.pdf -b one_entry_each_doc -o Analog_2015-03_sejda.pdf'
12:35:55.549 Java version: '1.7.0_75'
12:35:55.649 
To report a bug, please visit http://www.sejda.org/issuetracker 
Helpful information to include when raising a bug: the input files, the command line executed and the stack trace below.

12:35:55.658 Too many options given for input. Please use only one of the following options: --directory --filesListConfig --file
org.sejda.model.exception.SejdaRuntimeException: Too many options given for input. Please use only one of the following options: --directory --filesListConfig --file
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.extractPdfMergeInputs(MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.java:82) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.toTaskParameters(MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.java:54) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.toTaskParameters(MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.java:37) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.CliInterfacedTask.getTaskParameters(CliCommand.java:377) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.CliCommand.parseTaskParameters(CliCommand.java:314) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.SejdaConsole.executeCommand(SejdaConsole.java:106) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.SejdaConsole.doExecute(SejdaConsole.java:80) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.SejdaConsole.execute(SejdaConsole.java:56) ~[sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
    at org.sejda.cli.Main.main(Main.java:38) [sejda-console-1.0.0.M10.jar:na]
Exception in thread "main" org.sejda.model.exception.SejdaRuntimeException: Too many options given for input. Please use only one of the following options: --directory --filesListConfig --file
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.extractPdfMergeInputs(MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.java:82)
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.toTaskParameters(MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.java:54)
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.toTaskParameters(MergeCliArgumentsTransformer.java:37)
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.CliInterfacedTask.getTaskParameters(CliCommand.java:377)
    at org.sejda.cli.transformer.CliCommand.parseTaskParameters(CliCommand.java:314)
    at org.sejda.cli.SejdaConsole.executeCommand(SejdaConsole.java:106)
    at org.sejda.cli.SejdaConsole.doExecute(SejdaConsole.java:80)
    at org.sejda.cli.SejdaConsole.execute(SejdaConsole.java:56)
    at org.sejda.cli.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

I fail to see where I am providing too many options.  Please point out my error.  Thank you for your assistance.

Dave

Comment: I just thought of one possibility and added a "-d ." to my options.  That appears to have been the problem, despite the fact that the documentation indicates that "-d" is optional as is the "-e" I am using.  From my experience it appears that "-d" is required if "-e" is to be used.  So my problem here was a misunderstanding of the documentation and an error message about too many options when the actual issue was a missing required option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide at least one option that specifies which input files to use: one of `-d`, `-e` or `-f`.

I think you found a bug though. When no cli option providing inputs are passed, Sejda shows the error about too many options being provided, which is confusing.

https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/issues/168

I've fixed it, thanks for your feedback.